# xsl:import conventions about general stylesheet's properties

Tags: xslt, import, xslt-1.0, global

The [XSLT1 spec, `xsl:import` section](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#import) is not very clear/direct about things like:

- if both have `output` tag, what will be used?
- if both have a namespace attributes (`xmlns:xsl`) or other global (ex. `exclude-result-prefixes`), what will be used globally?
- ... etc...

I have a "hub XSLT" with all attributes and global tags... But now I am importing some XSLTs that are also standalone XSLTs, so perhaps in the future I will notice surprises... To avoid surprises, this question.

Summarizing the question:

**Can all the XSLTs be "empty of gobal tags" if the "hub XSLT" has all of them?  If there is conflict, what are the precedence rules?**

Comment: So, where do we stand with this? Did you read my answer? Is there something missing from it? Did you consider accepting my answer?

Comment: @MathiasMüller Hi, sorry. Your answer is about XSLT 2.0 (? you cited XSLT2), the question about 7-years older standard and libs, XSLT v1... Please indicate what parts of the answer are about v1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are asking if it is sufficient to have all the declarations only in the importing module, but at the same time you are saying that all modules are also "standalone" XSLT stylesheets? Makes no sense to me. Obviously, an imported module would not be a full-flegded stylesheet anymore if it did not have declarations and, in the case of missing namespace declarations, it would not be well-formed XML anymore. And a stylesheet that is malformed XML would be utterly useless.

---

In general, imported declarations (declarations that physically reside in the imported stylesheet module) have a lower precedence. But some qualifications are needed.

**`xsl:output/@method`**

`xsl:output` is a declaration, if there is conflict between stylesheets, the importing module takes precedence over the imported one. Consequently, the output method declared in the importing stylesheet will be used. But a caveat here: not all attributes of `xsl:output` are treated in the same way.

**Namespaces**

Namespaces (and thus prefixes) that are defined in the importing stylesheet are *not* available in the imported stylesheet. This means that if you define

```
xmlns:ns="www.namespace.com"
```

in the importing stylesheet, the prefix `ns` will not be connected to the namespace URI `"www.namespace.com"` in the imported module. In such a case, you need to redeclare the namespace.

And if you ponder this fact for a while, it becomes obvious why this is so: A stylesheet (module) does not need to be imported. It should always be possible to use it on its own or import it. The only way to make sure a stylesheet retains its independence is to declare all namespaces in it.

**`exclude-result-prefixes`**

For attributes like `exclude-result-prefixes` I quote Michael Kay<sup>1</sup>, saying that

> [t]he values of the `version`,`extension-element-prefixes`,`exclude-result-prefixes` and `xpath-default-namespace` attributes that apply to an element in the imported stylesheet, as well as `xml:lang` and `xml:space`, are those that were defined in the `<xsl:stylesheet>` element of their own module, not those on the `<xsl:stylesheet>` element of the importing module.

The easiest way to find the rules would of course be to simply *test*. In most cases, the test would be a pretty trivial one. For example, define two output methods in the stylesheet modules:

```
<xsl:output method="text"/>      <xsl:output method="xml"/>
```

and see if the output is text or XML.

And that's exactly how you should go about finding the rules for "...etc..." from your question.

---

<sup>1 Michael Kay, XSLT 2.0 and XPath 2.0 Programmer's Reference, p. 358</sup>

Comment: About "asking if it is sufficient to have all the declarations only in the importing module": yes. About "standalone": yes? The question is about "there are unspected side-effects??", "it is not a 'best practice'?"... The root (hub) XSLT is not standalone, but the "terminals" (importeds) are also used as standalone.

Comment: As commented above: please indicate if your answer (or parts) are about V1 or V2.

Comment: @PeterKrauss My answer fully applies to both XSLT 1.0 and 2.0 - XSLT 2.0 did not introduce any changes to either the syntax or the rules (again, this claim is made by Dr. Kay).